# Figuring Out Memory Leaks without Clang

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks, clang-static-analyzer

I'm trying to see if I can find some leaks myself in Apple's TopSongs app. Can someone help me out in at least one and how to identify what is in the Leaks reports and how I can get an idea on finding them?

ie: I got one like this:

```
#    Category    Event Type  Timestamp   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   GeneralBlock-448    Malloc  00:02.185   0x3f41220   448 libxml2.2.dylib xmlNewParserCtxt
```

From what I can tell, the method xmlNewParserCtxt is the problem, and it's not releasing an object, hence Malloc. The responsible library tells me it's the libxml2.2.dylib library with the problem, which I can't edit.

Am I heading in the right direction? If so, half the leaks are in that library and well, i can't edit that.

'

## UPDATE:

Check out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405098/apples-sample-app-topsongs-has-26-leaks-ugh).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a `xmlNewParserCtxt` was created (`malloc`'d)

```
xmlParserCtxt* context;
context = xmlNewParserCtxt();
```

and then not freed?

```
xmlFreeParserCtxt(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got Snow Leopard and Xcode 3.2 installed with the built-in Clang. Anyways, it seems like Apple's code has it's own leaks inside their libraries. I decided not to use Apple's TopSongs code.